# Automatically insert paragraph before citations

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

For a style file I would like to automatically generate an acknowledgement paragraph / section of text before the references (based on some options set by user-supplied macros). The approach should work with both `bibtex` and `biblatex`. How to do this?

When using bibtex I am able to achieve this by pre-pending to `thebibliography`:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \section{Acknowledgements}%
  Example text.%
}
```

This does not work with biblatex. I tried patching `\printbibliography`

```
\pretocmd\printbibliography{%
  \section{Acknowledgements}%
  Example text.%
}{}{}%
```

But this doesn't work. Is there an easy / elegant solution for this?

++++ Update to provide a MWE

Apologies for not providing an MWE.
Assume there is a template.bib which contains one reference:

```
@article{RSA78,
  author    = {Ronald L. Rivest and Adi Shamir and Leonard M. Adleman},
  title     = {A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems},
  pages     = {120--126},
  year      = {1978},
  journal   = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume    = {21},
  number    = {2},
  publisher = {ACM New York, NY, USA},
  doi       = {10.1145/359340.359342},
}
```

Then I would like to automatically insert a paragraph / section before the display of the references (without the author to modify commands on their end).
This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{template}
\end{document}
```

When using Bibtex I can achieve this using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \section*{Acknowledgements}%
  Section text.%
}

\begin{document}
This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{template}
\end{document}
```

How to do this using biblatex / biber?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{template.bib}
\begin{document}
This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using the notes option to `\printbibliography` does not achieve what I want.

Comment: Had you provided a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/105447), I might have gone for an answer. But I'm lazy today, so just the hint: look at the documentation for the `prenote` option of `\printbibliography` and `\defbibnote`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` already has infrastructure for this kind of insertion, there's no need to redefine internals to do it. Namely, the `prenote` option to `\printbibliography`, which allows you to select a bibnote defined with `\defbibnote`. You can set either at the time you call `\printbibliography` or set global defaults with `\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults`, depending on your actual use case. In the example, I'm setting the `prenote` as default and the `title` locally, as it seems to make more sense:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{template.bib}
\defbibnote{myprenote}{Section text.}
\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{prenote=myprenote}
\begin{document}
This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
\printbibliography[title=Acknowledgements]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: As cleared up in the comments (but the comment was edited later...), what was actually desired was something before the heading itself. For that, you can set a `\defbibheading`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{template.bib}
\defbibheading{myheading}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{Acknowledgements}%
  Section text.%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}
\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{heading=myheading}
\begin{document}
This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! This indeed allows for what I want. 

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{template.bib}
    \defbibnote{myprenote}{%
      Section text.%
      \section*{References}%
    }
    
    \DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{prenote=myprenote}
    \begin{document}
    This is an example citation~\cite{RSA78}.
    \printbibliography[title=Acknowledgements]
    \end{document}

Comment: @jwbos See edit.

Comment: This indeed answers the question!